# Hebrew line numbers in reledmac

Tags: reledmac

Your favorite reledmac newbie is back! Is there a way to have the line numbers in Hebrew numbering? `\linenumberstyle` only has alph, arabic, and roman options according to the documentation.

Comment: please, as in general, add  MWE…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, reledmac provides only options provided by default LaTeX.

But as you use bidi (if I use the MWE you send on your other questions, but please ALWAYS send a MWE), you can define your own `\linenumrepR` command to set the representation of right line number.

In your preamble add:

```
\def\linenumrepR#1{%
  \begingroup%
    \hebrewfont%
    \hebrewnumeral{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

- `\linenumrepR` is called by reledpar to typeset right side number.
- `\begingroup`…`\endgroup`is required to set the font change to be only local
- `\hebrewfont` select hebrew font
- `\hebrewnumeral` provided by polyglossia, format a number in hebrew.