# reledmac subline numbers rtl

Tags: polyglossia, line-numbering, hebrew, reledmac, right-to-left

I am trying to use reledmac subline numbers with a rtl text using polyglossia. My issue: The subline dividers seem to be rendering incorrectly.
I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370601/hebrew-line-numbers-in-reledmac) question/answer, which might serve as a workaround, but I did not understand it, and it would be a workaround regardless.
This is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar]{reledmac} 
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=arabic]{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Hadasim CLM}
\newcommand{\vart}[1]{\Afootnote{#1}}   % Macro to make adding notes a bit quicker.
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\firstsublinenum{1}
\sublinenumincrement{1}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
 שלום\footnote{קרי}
זוהי עובדה מבוססת שדעתו של הקורא תהיה מוסחת עלידי טקטס קריא כאשר הוא יביט בפריסתו.
זוהי עובדה מבוססת שדעתו של הקורא תהיה מוסחת עלידי טקטס קריא כאשר הוא יביט בפריסתו.
\startsub

זוהי עובדה מבוססת שדעתו של הקורא תהיה מוסחת עלידי טקטס קריא כאשר הוא יביט בפריסתו.
זוהי עובדה מבוססת שדעתו של הקורא תהיה מוסחת עלידי טקטס קריא כאשר הוא יביט בפריסתו.זוהי עובדה מבוססת שדעתו של הקורא תהיה מוסחת עלידי טקטס קריא כאשר הוא יביט בפריסתו.
\pend 
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Changing polyglossia to use Hebrew numerals only makes things worse, aside from forcing footnotes to be in Hebrew numerals.
Also, the first line seems to be thrown off by the footnote, so the line number prints in the gap that appears after the 1st line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome !

The definition of the subline separator is linked to the `\Xsublinesep` hook.

The default definition is `\fullstop`, which is an historical (r)(e)(l)edmac macro, defined as

```
\newcommand*{\fullstop}{\textnormal{.}}
```

The reason why there is historically a `\textnormal` around the stop is, I guess, to avoid problem when switching between non latin font, etc. Also, to avoid bold/italic.

But in your case, it creates a problem, because it change from `\hebrewfont` to normal font, and so switch from RTL to LTR.

So, what you can do is, instead of calling `\fullstop`, just call a direct dot. So add in your preamble

```
\Xsublinesep{.}
```